# Grails GORM gives hibernate exception when querying domain object that was already queried

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

I have a Grails app where controller calls transactional service. The service has the following body

```
def rep = Rep.findById(2708280)

def r = Rep.findById(2708280)
r.accountNumber = "123423565476"
r.save(failOnError: true)

def list = Rep.findAllByRtnAndAccountNumber(
        rep.rtn, rep.accountNumber)
```

When the last line in the method is called, I get the following hibernate exception:

```
    ERROR an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session) [AssertionFailure]
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: collection [com.mydomain.InnerObject.assignedTests] was not processed by flush()
at org.hibernate.engine.CollectionEntry.postFlush(CollectionEntry.java:228)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.postFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:352)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:65)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1185)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1709)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.FindAllByPersistentMethod$1.doInHibernate(FindAllByPersistentMethod.java:113)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeFind(HibernateTemplate.java:348)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.FindAllByPersistentMethod.doInvokeInternalWithExpressions(FindAllByPersistentMethod.java:73)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod.java:543)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod.java:417)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.java:79)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.java:72)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9819.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:102)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2.call(GormStaticApi.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureStaticMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureStaticMetaMethod.java:62)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:91)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at com.mydomaint.MyService.$tt__process(MyService.groovy:118)
```

where 'com.mydomain.InnerObject' is an inner object of my domain object above.

```
static belongsTo = [owner: InnerObject]

InnerObject owner
```

and assignedTests is a property of InnerObject domain:

```
static hasMany = [assignedVouchers: AssignedTests]
```

Is there anything I am missing here? What does this exception mean?

Comment: Does the problem go away if you change `r.save(failOnError: true)` to `r.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)`?

Comment: Yes and no. I have 3k of such domain objects handled in a loop, and at some point it happens for me again. With flush:true it happens more rarely though.

Answer (score 0):

That happens probably because you have two objects of the same instance in the session with different values.

`rep` is unmodified and `r` is modified (and persisted)

When you call `list`, Hibernate tries to flush the session and it gets confused

```
at org.hibernate.engine.CollectionEntry.postFlush(CollectionEntry.java:228)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.postFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:352)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:65)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1185)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1709)
```

Instead you could try to hold the parameters you pass to the list in separate variables. Try that:

```
def r = Rep.findById(2708280)
def p1 = r.rtn
def p2 = r.accountNumber

r.accountNumber = "123423565476"
r.save(failOnError: true)

def list = Rep.findAllByRtnAndAccountNumber(p1, p2)
```